# Do the tasks on the active workspace have higher priority?

Tags: workspaces, process-priority

For this time I won't bother anyone with technical problems. I just had a philosophical question. Well it's in the title, I guess it's clear enough :p

Well actually the question is more general: what are workspaces? Do they differ only by what is displayed on it (the processes being totally independently defined/prioritized)? Or do they really kindof own or are connected to the applications you launch on them?

Yop, that's all! Thanks you for reading!

Julien

Comment: This is a very cool idea, although I think it would be pretty hard to implement well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workspaces are just something to structure your windows better. They don't group processes, or edit their priority.